# GAE: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson.set

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

Starting from June, 12 my app that is used DriveAPI faced the following error (it's shown in GAE server log):

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson.set**(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/api/client/json/GenericJson;
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets$Details.set(GoogleClientSecrets.java:166)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets$Details.set(GoogleClientSecrets.java:87)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:357)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:586)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:350)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:586)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:289)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:266)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseAndClose(JsonParser.java:141)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.fromInputStream(JsonFactory.java:223)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.load(GoogleClientSecrets.java:195)
    at finbudget.server.handlers.lists.cronimport.AutoImportBackend.doImport(AutoImportBackend.java:112)
    at finbudget.server.handlers.lists.cronimport.AutoImportBackend.doPost(AutoImportBackend.java:76)
......

It seems like this problem comes with 1.8.1 version of AppEngine release. Before it worked well... Did someone have the same problem? And what could be the solution for this?

Comment: You can answer and accept your own questions on SO, in fact it's more helpful so people don't click on the question thinking it's unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a classpath collision.

If `war/WEB-INF/lib` contains multiple versions of the DriveAPI jars, strange issues may result from the wrong version loading during runtime. Removing outdated jars solves the problem.

(Note: I copied and formatted the answer that the original asker added to the question via an edit. I did this as a cleanup task.)